# How to add string to second line?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to append string to Label.

str1 = Hello;

Str2 = Hi;

I am able to append two string but it shows me like "Hello Hi", I want second string in new line like

Hello

Hi

Please any one suggest me how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an escape sequence. "\n".

```
NSString *str1 = @"Hello";
NSString *str2 = @"Hi";
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", str1, str2];
```

finalString contains the result that you want.

Answer (score 1):

The newline character in Objective-C is `\n`